# is there any way to broadcast a single http request to multiple server at the same time

Tags: http

Is there any way to send (broadcast) a single request to multiple server?

My requirement is I need a module which can send a single request to multiple servers(generally speaking broadcast the request).After it wait for the response for a certain time say 5 mili sec) and the response it get from from different server it either clubbed together and send back to the client or based on a parameter in the response(suppose price)it send the response to the client.

e.g: request(get the price) need to be send to server1,server2, server3 and server 4 at a time. server1 response: price:$5 server2 response: price:$3 server3 does not respond back in 5 milisec server4 response: price:$8

My module either send back the server4 response back to client as it has highest price or it can send all the response to client by clubbed together and client will validate on the price.

Comment: A single request can only go to a single server, but you can send separate, similar requests to each of several servers. But you won't get more specific answers unless you clarify what technology you're using to make the requests and what you've tried so far.

Comment: **Excact** duplicate of [Is there in nginx module to send(broadcast) a single request to multiple server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654964/is-there-in-nginx-module-to-sendbroadcast-a-single-request-to-multiple-server).  **Do not** repost questions if they do not get immediate answers.

Comment: We are using C++ and HTTP protocol to send the request.I have tried curl.1st I am creating the number of threads as per the request and each thread is responsible for sending one request in curl.I am joining the thread and sending back the response to the client.But thread joining is not so good idea.I am looking for any web server like apache and nginx.But apache is very slow as our request is very high and latency should be very low.I have not got any solution in nginx yet......

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cURL multi interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) to do this.

Set up a separate handle for each request, initialize a multi-handle and add your individual request handles to it. Execute the threads and go into a wait loop for their responses/timeouts. Afterwards you parse each response to gather all of the results.

Comment: Yes you are right,I also thought of the same, but the only problem in the curl is, it is slow.Our platform needs to send 50k request per sec to 20-30 servers.My doubt is if curl ll able to handle these many request and if I ll wait for the response in the thread at some point of time, i ll be out of thread.